# Java position of the mouse on the screen

Tags: java, opengl

I am making this GUI where you have icons that should always stay at the same position on the screen and I want to make them do something once I click on them.

In my case I've made this neat cancel symbol which I placed on the upper right corner of my lwjgl display - I've made this code here to enable clicking on it:

```
private void CloseIcon()
{
    if(Input.GetMousePosition().GetX() > 1175 && Input.GetMousePosition().GetX() < 1215 &&
       Input.GetMousePosition().GetY() > 685 && Input.GetMousePosition().GetY() < 715)
    {
        if(Input.GetMouse(0)) {
        System.out.println("closing porgram..");
        }
    }
}
```

Now there are two issues with this method and I was wondering If there's a better way to do it?

Issue 1: When I change the resolution of my display, or if I go to full screen, obviously the definition for x and y aren't the same anymore - what's a better way to define the location of the icon?

Issue 2: At the moment I have the icon object move together with the camera, like that it always stays at the same place on the screen - still is there a better way to position the object in openGL so it stays always at the same place no matter what the camera is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are using the lwjgl, you can define from the beginning your own resolution, and don't have to get heat up with that:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width,height));
Display.create();
```

or for fullscreen

```
Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
Display.setFullscreen(true);
Display.create();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but since I'm using lwjgl couldn't I use Display.getWidth() and Display.getHeight instead?

Comment: see the new anwser... so you won't have any trouble to calculate the middle point from the "screen"/"window" and even if you change screen resolution.

Comment: Well yes but when I change the resolution at one point the positions will all be messed up ... for example if I would allow to change the resolution while the program is running, then all positions for the mouse will be at the wrong playe..??

Comment: if you have the resolution A x B and change to C x D where C / A = factorx in X axi and D / C = factory in Y axis, so um can apply the factor in each point/object created!